# Print Microsoft Office and PDF files in Java

Tags: java, api, pdf, printing, ms-office

I am looking for APIs for Java that can print Microsoft Office and PDF files. I would also like to provide print specifications, even if there is no software for opening these files on the system. Commercial libraries are fine. Can you recommend any?

Comment: You can use our product Gnostice PDFOne (for Java) and here is our PDF printing demo - [How to Print a PDF Document in Java](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=160&t=How_to_Print_a_PDF_Document_in_Java). PDFOne comes with a royalty-free commercial license.

Comment: i dont want any dialog to come in front!! i just want to pass all specifications from my applicartion

Comment: If you don't want the dialog, you need not call the PDFPrinter.showPrintDialog() method. Instead, call the PdfPrinter.print(String pageRange, int numOfCopies) method. It is mentioned in the article in the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Printing of PDF here is the Best solution for free!!Use the PDFBox ..

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;


public class PrintPDF
{

    private static final String PASSWORD     = "-password";
    private static final String SILENT       = "-silentPrint";
    private static final String PRINTER_NAME = "-printerName";

    /**
     * private constructor.
     */
    private PrintPDF()
    {
        //static class
    }


    public static void main( String pdfFilepath,String printerindx ) throws Exception
    {
        String password = "";
        String pdfFile = pdfFilepath;
        boolean silentPrint = true;

        PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();            


        if( pdfFile == null )
        {
            usage();
        }

        PDDocument document = null;
        try
        {
            document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );

            if( document.isEncrypted() )
            {
                document.decrypt( password );
            }
            PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            if(printerindx != null )
            {
                PrintService[] printService = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

                printJob.setPrintService(printService[Integer.parseInt(printerindx)]);


            }
            txt=new PDDocument(document);
            if( silentPrint )
            {


                document.silentPrint( printJob );
            }
            else
            {
                document.print( printJob );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if( document != null )
            {
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage requirements and exit.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java org.apache.pdfbox.PrintPDF [OPTIONS] <PDF file>\n" +
                "  -password  <password>        Password to decrypt document\n" +
                "  -silentPrint                 Print without prompting for printer info\n"
        );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: But i still need a solution for MS office files!

Comment: Convert the Office document to PDF first, and print that.  For docx, try docx4j; for xlsx and old binary formats, try POI or, for a non Java approach, OpenOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at OpenOffice API, there are some [printing examples provided](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling). OpenOffice can open MS Office documents but the given API is very very limited.

Answer (score 1):

Aspose has a suite of products for working with Word, Excel, PDF. You can export to different formats, including PDF, and print.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display-table tags of struts in java to export your data into xls, pdf, cvs format and then can print as well.

Syntax is very simple just provide your collection to the display table and it will display the contents of the collection itself on the jsp and if you set "export = true", you can easily export your file in to pdf or xls formats.

Visit here:

http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tlddoc/display/table.html

Answer (score 0):

try Apache POI for Microsoft docs http://poi.apache.org/

For print setup refer this url http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPrintSetup.html